# Graph Theoretic Property of distance regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

So I am current studying distance regular graphs on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-regular_graph.

In Wikipedia, it states that $$\frac{k_{j+1}}{k_j}=\frac{b_j}{c_{j+1}} \ \forall \ j ,\ 0 \leq j<d$$.

But I can't seem to prove this. Can sombebody give me some hints ?

---

To clarify some definitions, we say that a graph $G$ with diameter $d$ is distance-regular whenever there is an intersection array of constants $[{b_0,…,b_{d-1};c_1,c_2,…,c_d}]$ so that for every vertex $x$ of $G$ and every $y\in G_i(x) (0\leq i\leq d)$ we have $b_i=|G(y)\cap G_{i+1}(x)|$ when $i\neq d$ and $c_i=|G(y)\cap G_{i-1}(x)|$ when $i\neq 0$. Furthermore, $k_i:=|G_i(x)|$ where $G_i(x)$ is the $i$th neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: To keep your question open it is necessary to add to your question at least the definition of the numbers $k_i$. If you are able to do so, read the basic definitions in Brower, Cohen, Neumaier's book "Distance-Regular Graphs" on page 14.

Comment: @kabenyuk I have added the basic definitions required. Also, I have checked the book (https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=v6brCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) that you recommended but don’t see the proof of the result I am look for.

Comment: Yes, I pointed to the wrong pages. The necessary definitions in this book are on page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain the formula you write about. In doing so, it is helpful to look at the picture.

[image]

So, once again, the notation:

$G_i(u)$ is the set of all vertices $G$ at distance $i$ from vertex $u$, and

$G_i=G_i(u)$, $c_i=|G_{i-1}\cap N(v)|$, $b_i=|G_{i+1}\cap N(v)|$, $k_i=|G_i|$.

The symbol $N(v)$ denotes the set of neighbors of the vertex $v$ in the graph $G$.
It is also important to remember that the numbers $b_i,c_i,k_i$ do not depend on the choice of vertices $u,v$.
It is only important that the distance $d(u,v)$ is $i$, i.e. $d(u,v)=i$.

Now compute in two different ways the number of (red) edges $xy$ of graph $G$, where $x\in G_i$ and $y\in G_{i+1}$.

On the one hand, each vertex of $x\in G_i$ has exactly $b_i$ neighbors in $G_{i+1}$. Hence there are $k_i\cdot b_i$ of these edges.

On the other hand, each vertex $y\in G_{i+1}$ has exactly $c_{i+1}$ neighbors in $G_i$. Hence there are $k_{i+1}\cdot c_{i+1}$ such edges.

It follows that $k_i\cdot b_i=k_{i+1}\cdot c_{i+1}$.

Comment: nicely explained with good diagram for illustration (+1) May I know what software you used to draw the diagram? May want to draw my own diagrams in the future.

Comment: @Explorer1234 Thank you. The drawing is made with LaTeX+TikZ.